# Custom view with height and width same as background drawable

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

am developing an android app where i have a custom view(extending Surfaceview)..Now am facing an issue that the view is always setting it height and width to match_parent..

I have changed it to wrap_content in Xml layout file and nothing changed , still it's in full screen even in Graphical Layout(design view of android xml ui) and in runtime aswell..

What i need is, I am changing it's background dynamically using images from gallery..
Like this,

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

        myDrawableView.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

i want the view in such a way that the background image will fit in screen and view will wrap this background image and thereby it's size would be same as size of that background image

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: see onMeasure method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the onMeasure() method, look at the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom and the LabelView sample in your SDK directory to learn how to do it.